# What is control of normative doctrine in Hobbes?

Tags: political-philosophy, hobbes

In Hobbes [political theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hobbes-moral/#Abs) sovereignty is sustained by certain *powers*; these are the powers of:

> legislation, adjudication, enforcement, taxation, war-making and the less familiar power of control of normative doctrine

But what meant by the last power? That is what is meant by 'control of normative doctrine'? I would suggest education and regulation of media as this shapes public discourse (the 'national conversation); but is this correct?

Is there a single word that covers this? I would suggest propaganda, except this has strong pejorative undertones.

Public relations suggests itself; but to my mind this is more closely associated with corporations than governance.

Comment: hobbes made me paranoid, but i know he's still a little current, so thanks :)

Comment: @mathematician: no doubt certain hobbites are enough to make anyone paranoid; but it's probably worth finding out what he had to say, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the *SEP* entry gives us no reference to Hobbes' works or terms; having said that, I think that a plausible interpretation is "religious doctrines and laws".

See Glen Newey, [Hobbes and Leviathan](https://books.google.it/books?id=PACDAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2008), page 153 :

> (*Leviathan*, page 378): “It is the civil sovereign that is to appoint judges, and interpreters of the canonical scriptures; for it is he that makes them laws”. There is a good reason for this: Hobbes thought that the “person” of the sovereign (whether an individual or assembly) could be the only source of
>   political, ecclesiastical and juridical authority.
>
> This was not because Hobbes believed that the sovereign was likely to be more skilful at Biblical interpretation than everyone else. His point was rather, as with the written civil laws, that scripture does not interpret itself, that the divergences in private readings of it are liable (then if not now) to provoke civil strife, and therefore the interests of peace are best served by making the sovereign’s interpretation of it authoritative. Religious law in *Leviathan* is the ecclesiastical equivalent of road-safety legislation: it matters little which side of the road people drive on, as long as everybody drives on the same side.

Comment: +1: I've accepted your answer - which is great; but just want to make clear to anyone else passing by who may have a possible answer, that I was looking for an answer relating to how we think of governance now, as opposed to then (ie Hobbes times).

Comment: @MoziburUllah - in "contemporary times" we have to consider *totalitarian* states, like nazi or bolscevism; in this case, yes : "normative doctrine" must be propaganda, and "state ideology". You have to take into account that hobbesian's *state* is not democratic, but absolutistic.

Comment: Possibly; but I'm more concerned by what constitutes sovereignty and governance: even democracies have to inculcate democratic values; ie people have to abide by the democratic process and it's this sense of normative doctrine I think the SEP is getting at.

Comment: I think it's close to what Chomsky calls manufacturing consent; except he uses it in a pejorative sense.